# Understanding the form of the raising and lowering operators matrices for angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators

I have a system with angular momentum $s=1$ and I can show that the raising and lowering operators for are given by $$S_{\pm}=\sqrt{s(s+1)-m(m\pm1)}\hbar\delta_{m^\prime,m\pm1}$$
Clearly $m=-1,0,1$ so as $\sqrt{s(s+1)-m(m\pm1)}$ is real and greater than zero this restricts the choices of $m \text{ and } m^\prime$ to $m^\prime=0, m=1 $ and $m^\prime=-1,m=0$. This gives the matrix $$S_{+}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
0&0&\sqrt{2}\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
So then, by reference to $\delta_{m^\prime,m+1}$, surely we would seek values s.t.  $m^\prime=m+1$ implying that $m=0, m=1 $. Therefore how does one deal with zero indices, that make no sense given the definition of $\delta_{m^\prime,m\pm1}$, to arrive at the above matrix for $S_{+}$, and by extension $S_{-}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by zero indices?

Comment: Well m'=m+1 for the delta to be equal to 1 so if m'= 1 then m=0. And m will denote the index of an element

Comment: What is there to deal with? You have a matrix element for a 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write $S_\pm$ in that form, it's more convenient to explicitly show the matrix indices
$$(S_{\pm})_{m',m}=\sqrt{s(s+1)-m(m\pm1)}\,\hbar\,\delta_{m^\prime,m\pm1}\,.$$

The state $|m\rangle$ is the state with a $1$ in the entry $m$ and zero otherwise. So we can write it as follows: $$(|m\rangle)_{m'} = \delta_{m' m}\,.$$

This gives (indices repeated are summed over)
$$
\begin{aligned}
(S_+)_{m',m''}(| m\rangle)_{m''} &= \sqrt{s(s+1)-m''(m''+1)}\,\hbar\,\delta_{m',m''+1} \delta_{m'' m} = \\&=
\sqrt{s(s+1)-m(m+1)}\,\hbar\,\delta_{m',m+1} = \\&=
\sqrt{s(s+1)-m(m+1)}\,\hbar\,(|m+1\rangle)_{m'}\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
Dropping the explicit indices
$$
S_+ |m\rangle = \sqrt{s(s+1)-m(m+1)}\,\hbar\,|m+1\rangle\,.
$$
This is to show that regarding $m$ inside $|m\rangle$ as an index is dangerous: it does not behave like an index! It is a label for a vector, and the result is that matrices seem to act on it from the right rather than from the left.

I admit I wasn't sure whether that was your doubt or not. If not, ignore all this if it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

We are working in a basis where we have
$$|+\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
~~~~~~~~~
|0\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
~~~~~~~~~
|-\rangle=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
and we would want the operator $S_+$ to be such that:
$$S_+|+\rangle=0~~~~~~~~~~~~S_+|0\rangle=\sqrt{2}|+\rangle~~~~~~~~~~~~ S_+|-\rangle=\sqrt{2}|0\rangle$$
And the $3\times3$ matrix that gives us this result is exactly
$$S_{+}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
0&0&\sqrt{2}\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$